# How caffe decide every layer type with cudnn nor not?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I find  that  caffe  can  use  different  layer type(native or  cudnn)  for  the 
same  layer (such  as   poollayer) ,but  I  can't find  the code deciding whether to decide this ?